# Angular Global Functions

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, jwt, web-frontend

I am building an angular application that supports JWT authentication. I build my JWT server using Spring Boot. A user provides his/her credentials for authentication. After a successful authentication, a response containing the access token and authentication will be forwarded to the user.
There is a exp value in my JWT access token containing the token lifespan. The refresh token is persisted in a DB.
To get a new access token, you have to sent a request with this header
--->>>X-Auth: refreshToken<<<--- to get a new access token.
I implemented a function that will resend a request for an access token using the refresh token.
I had tried implementing the function to run the function globally but to no avail. I wish to find out if there is a way that I could run the function once globally in my angular app.

```
/***Login sample request***/
{
    "password": "secret123",
    "username": "nkengbeza"
}

/***Login sample response***/
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJua2VuZ2JlemEiLCJhdXRoIjpbeyJhdXRob3JpdHkiOiJBRE1JTiJ9XSwidG9rZW5fdHlwZSI6ImFjY2Vzc190b2tlbiIsImlhdCI6MTU0ODY2OTE0MSwiZXhwIjoxNTQ4NjcyNzQxfQ.oaWOIaeMqLg35unM82bcNg88ga030m5J1k7E5EM2O0s",
    "refresh_token": "a102c7a063c7f149bcb276eadf83c0c61659ff9b37c0a8ab7d29e92c08ac94e7aa99abc5e9a3c1c59da4e66f1ada0c6a02dca2f577a4aa3f81885c73f5a879d1"
}

/***Request for an access token using a valid refresh token***/
reLogin() {
    (async () => {
      const resp = await fetch(AppRoutes.RELOAD_AUTH, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Auth': this.getAuth().refreshToken
        }
      });

      if (resp.status !== 200) {
        this.doLogout();
      }

      const content = await resp.json();

      const accessToken = content.access_token;
      const tokenInfo = this.getDecodedAccessToken(accessToken); // decode token
      const auth = new Auth();

      auth.refreshToken = content.refresh_token;
      auth.role = tokenInfo.auth[0];
      const expireDate = tokenInfo.exp; // get token expiration dateTime

      this.setAccessToken(accessToken);
      this.setAuth(auth);

    })();
  }
```

Comment: you want to do that once on load?

Comment: Nope. After the initial login I want it to run in a setInterval() continuously.

Comment: This is the auth service? You put the token in the local storage ? With provideIn root you should have only one service for all the components.

Comment: I have only an auth service. My tokens are all saved in the cookies. I wish to exec the reLogin() once maybe in some kinda global service.